# How to correctly handle Botocore exceptions and AWS service exceptions

Tags: python, boto3, botocore

I'm new to the python and would like to learn it proper way rather than just solving the problem. So I'm just come up with this to learn something properly.

When reading [this](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/error-handling.html) documentation, I understand there are two type of exceptions we need to handle when working with boto3 (Botocore exceptions and AWS service exceptions).

I'm writing a small Lambda function like below and it works well. I just want to know is there anything else I have to do to handle the errors/exceptions properly?. (Please note, I do not need any custom error messages to pass by using `if err.response['Error']['Code']`. I just only need to make sure my function handles both botocore exceptions and AWS service exceptions. Can someone please explain, what I did here is correct or advice any improvements to be made?

Also what is the different between when I use `from botocore.exceptions import ClientError` and `except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as error:` directly in my code. Is there best practices to do so?

```html
import boto3
import logging
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

client = boto3.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi')

try:
    logger.info('Starting Report Creation')
    response = client.start_report_creation(
        S3Bucket='my-bucket'
    )

except ClientError as e:
        logger.error(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

You asked

> different between when I use from botocore.exceptions import ClientError and except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as error

Either are fine, I prefer the latter.

Im my experience, the ClientError is more of a generic exception and can be used. I believe each boto3.resource (resource object) has its own exceptions see: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/error-handling.html#catching-exceptions-when-using-a-resource-client

The documentation states you can leverage the basic `ClientError` and reference exact error via the response. This is what [the documentation states](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/error-handling.html#parsing-error-responses-and-catching-exceptions-from-aws-services)

> Unlike botocore exceptions, AWS service exceptions aren't statically defined in Boto3. This is due to errors and exceptions from AWS services varying widely and being subject to change. To properly catch an exception from an AWS service, you must parse the error response from the service. The error response provided to your client from the AWS service follows a common structure and is minimally processed and not obfuscated by Boto3.

> Using Boto3, the error response from an AWS service will look similar to a success response, except that an Error nested dictionary will appear with the ResponseMetadata nested dictionary. Here is an example of what an error response might look like:

```json
{
    'Error': {
        'Code': 'SomeServiceException',
        'Message': 'Details/context around the exception or error'
    },
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        'RequestId': '1234567890ABCDEF',
        'HostId': 'host ID data will appear here as a hash',
        'HTTPStatusCode': 400,
        'HTTPHeaders': {'header metadata key/values will appear here'},
        'RetryAttempts': 0
    }
}
```

> Boto3 classifies all AWS service errors and exceptions as ClientError exceptions. When attempting to catch AWS service exceptions, one way is to catch ClientError and then parse the error response for the AWS service-specific exception.

> Using Amazon Kinesis as an example service, you can use Boto3 to catch the exception LimitExceededException and insert your own logging message when your code experiences request throttling from the AWS service.

```py
import botocore
import boto3
import logging

# Set up our logger
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()

client = boto3.client('kinesis')

try:
    logger.info('Calling DescribeStream API on myDataStream')
    client.describe_stream(StreamName='myDataStream')

except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as error:
    if error.response['Error']['Code'] == 'LimitExceededException':
        logger.warn('API call limit exceeded; backing off and retrying...')
    else:
        raise error
```